# How to open .p extension file in matlab or as a text document

Tags: matlab

Error using open .Cannot edit the P-file

How can I resolve this error? I only need to just see the content of the file.

Comment: But a `.p` file is deliberately obfuscated to prevent anyone just seeing its contents.  That's not an error you're looking at, it's a feature !  Are you trying to inspect someone else's proprietary code ?

Comment: See `help code` or `doc pcode`. They're deliberately obfuscated files. You're out of luck unless you can find the the `.m` file that was used to create it.

Comment: If you achieve a way of editing a p-file, please contact matlab ASAP and get a job there in crypography and file protection.

Comment: .P files are designed to prevent you from seeing or editing it.  There is no way to do this.

Comment: @AnderBiguri `.p` files are obfuscated, not encrypted. There's no cryptography involved.

Comment: @SamRoberts Yesm yes, just trying to be a bit sarcastic here! :P